# Using Fastapi and Modal Labs, how can I set the directory path to the tEmplates folder/

Tags: modal-dialog, fastapi

I am deploying a Fastapi app using modal labs' containers. I want to create / mount a tempalates directory for my html files. Here is the code snippet:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pathlib import Path

from modal import Image, Stub, Mount, asgi_app

app = FastAPI()
static_path = Path(__file__).with_name("templates").resolve()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

stub = Stub("ilovekiyomi")

image = Image.debian_slim().pip_install("jinja2").pip_install("uvicorn[standard]")

@app.get("/")
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

@stub.function(
    image=image,
    mounts=[Mount.from_local_dir(static_path, remote_path="/templates")],
)

@asgi_app()
def fastapi_app():
    app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="/templates", html=True))
   
    return app
```

There is no error when I deploy using modal `deploy main.py` but when I go to the URL, the error message in modal logs is as follows:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-15' coro=<FastAPI.__call__() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py:267> exception=TemplateNotFound('index.html')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 235, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 161, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/root/main.py", line 30, in index
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/templating.py", line 97, in TemplateResponse
    template = self.get_template(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/templating.py", line 84, in get_template
    return self.env.get_template(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 218, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
Request finished with status 500. (execution time: 0.9 ms, total latency: 1826.7 ms)
```

I feel as if I am almost there, can somebody help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the top two strategies outlined on this page? https://modal.com/docs/guide/custom-container